# When I lowercase with tr and update the value the new value is not there

Tags: bash

I am using build.spec aws beanstalk for my build project and here is my bash script:

```
      - stg="$STG.js"
      - stg= $stg | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
      - cat deployment-config/$stg >> src/tj-paths/pathExtensions.js
```

I pass Stg3 for $STG and after the following line:

```
stg= $stg | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

I expect stg to have the value of stg3 rather than Stg3

But still the value is Stg3
Any idea?

Comment: Is `$STG.js` an executable?  Or did you mean `str=$( echo "$STG".js | ...)`

Comment: @WilliamPursell no it is not executable. it is just a file name. so should I use ()?However I can see I get Stg3 from it correctly the only thing is the lower case does not take effect

Comment: Or perhaps you want `stg=$( < "$stg" tr ...)` . (using the file as input to `tr`)

Comment: That isn't bash code. Paste into shellcheck.net. Try this: `declare -l stg="$STG.js"` Now it's lowercase.

Comment: A [mcve] needs to be *working code* -- something we can actually run ourselves to see the same problem you're asking about, without unrelated issues. `- anything` isn't valid bash code. It might be part of a YAML document some tool munges to *generate* bash code, but it isn't valid bash itself (unless you have a command named `-` installed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
STG="TeStNaMe"

stg="$STG.js"
echo "  original: $stg"

stg=$(echo "$stg" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
echo "lower case: $stg"
```

output:

```
  original: TeStNaMe.js
lower case: testname.js
```